# Python min, max, mean, median code function define error

Tags: python, max, min, mean, median

**Here's my code:** Any help would be appreciated. Stuck on returning an error 'int' is not iterable and not sure where to go from there. Receiving error when running first part of my function at #minimum.

```
 #Minimum
min_val = min(input_list)
int(min_val)
return min_val

#Maximum
max_val = max(input_list)
int(max_val)
return max_val

#Mean
total = sum(input_list)
length = len(input_list)
for nums in [input_list]:
    mean_val = total / length
    float(mean_val)
    return mean_val

#Median
sorted(input_list)
med_val = sorted(lst)
lstLen = len(lst)
index = (lstLen - 1) // 2

if (lstLen % 2):
    return med_val[index]
else:
    return (med_val[index] + med_val[index + 1])/2.0

return min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val
```

Comment: In your function definition, the function is called `stats`. In your example where you call the function, you call a function named `get_stats`. Might that be why it isn't defined?

Comment: Why don't your write separate functions for `max`, `min`, `mean` ,`median`, and write a wrapper function to call them all.

Comment: Alternatively, why don't you use `max()`, and `min()` functions to get the maximum and minimum value in the list?

Comment: If you're going to create your own functions, start with defining a class and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a lot of baked-in functions and modules for doing common operations, i.e. basic stats (max, min, mean, median) via [the `statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html).

```
import statistics

my_list = list(range(51))

print(min(my_list)) # 0
print(max(my_list)) # 50
print(statistics.mean(my_list)) # 25.0
print(statistics.median(my_list)) # 25
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method named `get_stats`. Call `stats` instead.

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(my_list)
```

By the way, your code is totally wrong in terms of both indentation and logic. I'd recommend you to use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) functions to get the maximum and minimum values in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. This is actually my first program and I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.